# Value Error (If..else loop)

Tags: c, if-statement

This may be a dumb question but I really don't understand what is the error in this. The program works for all conditions except the condition for `A`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char card_name[3];
    puts("Enter the card name: ");
    scanf("%2s",card_name);
    int val = 0;
    //printf("%s",card_name);
    if(card_name[0] == 'K') {
        val = 10;
    }
    else if (card_name[0] == 'Q') {
        val = 10;
    }
    else if (card_name[0] == 'J') {
        val = 10;
    }
    else if (card_name[0] == 'A') {
        val == 11;
    }
    else {
        val = atoi(card_name);
    }

    printf("The card value is %d",val);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is correct for all except A.

```
Enter the card name: A
The card value is 0
```

Comment: D'oh! `{val == 11;}`

Comment: @Prathamesh Prabhudesai But seriously, enable compiler warnings, they might warn you about that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a silly programming error that no one would associate with the title of the question.

Comment: How can I enable gcc warnings? M new to programming

Comment: @PrathameshPrabhudesai: _gcc -Wall yourfile.c_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment operator `=` is not the same as the equality operator `==`.

```
else if(card_name[0] == 'A')
{val == 11;}  
      ^remove one =
```

`=` operator assign the value of right operand to its left operand while `==` compares the value of right and left operand.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(card_name[0] == 'A')
{val = 11;}
```

Answer (score 0):

== generate a boolean (true/false) used in if/else

So val == 11 check if val is equal to 11, and nothing else, that s why you have a error.

Some tips:

else {
        val = atoi(card_name);
    }

Will crash if I enter something else than A, K, Q, J or a number, let s say I enter azerty, you ll get a wrong result.

What you shoud do is

```
else if (card_name[0] >= '0' && card_name[0] <= '9') //Check if card_name[0] is a number
{
    val = atoi(card_name);
}
else
{
    printf("Wrong number\n");
    return -1; //Exit with error
}
```

EDIT: Correcting error pointed by Klas Lindbäck
Or you can keep your code and just add

```
else
{
    val = atoi(card_name);
    if (val == 0)
    {
        printf("Wrong number\n");
        return -1; //Exit with error
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Assuming you are with a linux OS (Debian, Ubuntu...)

Write a file named *compile.sh* which contain

```
if [ $# < 2 ]
then
    gcc -Wall $1
else
    gcc -Wall -o $2 $1
fi
```

So instead of typing *gcc -Wall -o output yourcode.c*, you can either write *sh compile.sh yourfile.c* or *sh compile.sh yourfile.c output*

Comment: @PrathameshPrabhudesai: You re welcome, don t worry, everybody made this mistake at some point in their learning. I ll suggest you to compile your code with all warning set (with gcc: _gcc yourfile.c -o output -Wall_). Also, think about accepting one of the answer, so someone which have a similar problem can have the good answer quickly.

Comment: `atoi` returns 0 instead of crashing if the string doesn't contain a number. Also, `atoi` expects a `char*`, not a `char`. Feeding it with a character, like `card_name[0]`, now that will most likely cause a crash.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Thank You. Everytime i will have to write -Wall for warnings? Accept the answer means what?

Comment: @PrathameshPrabhudesai: Yes you ll have to write -Wall everytime, if your OS is Linux, you can also write a script to add it for you. Accept the answer means click on the V sign at the left of the answer you want to accept, it will show it just under your question so that everyone can see it quickly

Comment: @PrathameshPrabhudesai: See EDIT 2

Comment: Can I know why I am downvoted?